# Installing the BTD400 Bluetooth adapter

Tags: bluetooth, adapter

I'm running Kubuntu 20.04 and I've just gotten a Kinivo BTD-400 USB Bluetooth Adapter.  The manufacturer claims it runs on a variety of systems including Ubuntu v12.04 and later.  Here are the instructions for installing  it:

Our BTD-300 and BTD-400 USB Bluetooth adapters are compatible with Ubuntu Linux and derivatives.  The required drivers are included with Ubuntu 12.04 and later.

For other Linux distributions, you’ll need to install the BlueZ Bluetooth stack and the BlueMan Bluetooth Manager.  Consult your distribution’s web site to see if the Bluez and Blueman software are available as a ready-to-install software package. [I have them both installed.]

Turning on Bluetooth

1. Plug in the Bluetooth adapter
2. Click the Bluetooth Icon in the toolbar
3. Click "Turn on Bluetooth"

Connecting a Device

1. Click the Bluetooth icon in the menu bar and select Set Up New Device.
2. Make the other Bluetooth device discoverable or visible and place it within 10 meters (about 33 feet) of your computer. Click Continue. Your computer will begin searching for devices.
3. If there are too many devices listed, use the Device type drop-down to display only a single type of device in the list.
4. Click PIN options to set how a PIN will be delivered to the other device.
5. The automatic PIN setting will use a six-digit numerical code. A device with no input keys or screen, such as a mouse or headset, may require a specific PIN such as 0000, or no PIN at all. Check your device's manual for the proper setting.
6. Choose an appropriate PIN setting for your device, then click Close.
7. Click Continue to proceed. If you did not choose a preset PIN, the PIN will be displayed on the screen.
8. If required, confirm the PIN on your other device. The device should show you the PIN you see on your computer screen, or may prompt you to enter the PIN. Confirm the PIN on the device, then click Matches.

I cannot find a toolbar that contains a Bluetooth icon, nor a menu that includes a Bluetooth icon with a *set up new device* option. I'm guessing that the user interface has changed considerably since 12.04 -- but how do I do this in Ubuntu 20.04?

I know that the device is being detected
because the light comes on and it shows up as an adapter.

Comment: Considering Ubuntu 12.04 LTS has reached the end of life on 28th April 2017. A lot of things have changed. If the maker of this device is wanting to run with Ubuntu they need to have made a more up to date driver.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS on a Nvidia Jetson Nano. The OS is an image from Nvidia with many data science packages bundled. I put in the Kinivo BTD-300. When I go to Bluetooth settings, it simply says no bluetooth adapter found. Kinivo driver page says the drivers should be bundled.